# Why am I getting the Yellow Screen Of Death on an Umbraco SurfaceController on a default/OOTB Umbraco installation?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

**My Question Is This**

What configuration step have I missed to make Mvc Surface Controllers work in Umbraco?

My theory is that since there is a folder in the default Umbraco install called `/umbraco/` which is used to connect to the CMS that the physical path is interfiering with the route `/umbraco/surface/{Controller}/{Action}` thus resulting in the ASP.NET YSOD (and an IIS 404 
when I try to access a controller on that route that isn't defined.)

---

**Background Information**

---

I have added this class to my `App_Code` folder in a freshly downloaded copy of Umbraco 6.1.6:

```
public class MembersController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello, Member!");
    }
}
```

When I navigate to what I think should be the route for my `Index()` method, I get a YSOD that says the resource could not be found:

[image: YSOD for route to path]

the code is not executed and the above error is displayed; however, if I change the Uri to garbage I get an IIS 404 error:

[image: IIS 404 error for route to non-existing path]

I started getting this in an existing site, thinking my site was screwed up I tried it in a new copy of Umbraco 6.1.6 and got the exact same results.

For the record, I have also tried `MembersSurfaceController` and its associated Uri, which has the exact same result as above. YSOD when I hit the valid route, and IIS 404 when I don't.

I have changed my `umbracoSettings.config` to MVC in the `/config/` directory as well.

---

**update**

---

I'm using the out-of-the-box `web.config` file, which has this:

```
 <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
         <remove name="UrlRewriteModule" />
         <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="UrlRewritingNet.Web.UrlRewriteModule, UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter" />
         .
         ..
         ...
```

On my default Umbraco site I don't have any rewrite rules defined; but on my actual site I have several rewrite rules in place. I'm thinking that's not causing it since I'm seeing the same behavior on both sites though...

I have tried removing `UrlRewrite` completely I get the same results.

---

Comment: did you check do you require UrlRewrite Module in IIS? it could be worth checking...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm running the out-of-the-box web.config.

Comment: I can replicate this issue, but only by placing my Controllers in the App_Code folder (Umbraco v6.1.3) - if they're complied, there seems to be no issue. It's a long shot, but could you compile the Controllers (by adding a Class Library, moving the Controllers to there and adding a reference to your Website to the Class Library if your project is a Website) and try again?

Comment: @milquetoastable I have not tried that yet (I will), but it feels like a lot of overkill for my current site.

Comment: Compiling the controller will resolve this issue, but I'm wondering if you (or anyone else) has ever figured out if it's possible to add Controllers in the App_Code folder. I'm experiencing the same issue myself at the moment. Creating a separate library appears to be some 'overkill'.

Comment: @Jan_V I have not figured it out yet, but I have not tried with more recent Umbraco versions either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach works for me in Umbraco 7.1, and I expect it to work in 6.1 as well:

Create folder called 'Controllers' within your App_Code folder, and put your surface controllers in there (so that they will be within the 'Controllers' namespace).

E.g. I have the following controller in the App_Code\Controllers folder (and hence, **within the 'Controllers' namespace**):

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class ServiceCentersController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult GetServiceCenters(string country = "", string region = "", string city = "")
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

My site runs on localhost, so I can invoke the GetServiceCenters action by navigating to:

```
http://localhost/umbraco/Surface/ServiceCenters/GetServiceCenters?country=aa&region=bb&city=cc
```

Comment: In order to get my controller working, I had to manually add the `namespace Controllers { .. }` code to my file. The folder name does not appear to matter, just the actual namespace. It also appears that using a Website project File=>New does insert the namespace as it does in a Web Application project type.

Comment: Do you create any associated stuff for this in the back office as well? Is there a link between the data types in the back office and surface controllers?

Comment: You do not need any specific setup in the back office to create surface controller as described in the answer.

Note that by inheriting from SurfaceController class you get access to Umbraco APIs which provide access to the CMS data represented by the data types specified in the back office.

Answer (score 0):

You need a namespace for your controller - the code posted above doesn't have any namespace:

```
public class MembersController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("Hello, Member!");
    }
}
```

That is why making a namespace of `Controllers` works ... but you could make this any logically named namespace you want.